# How to retrieve element from XElement

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to figure out the best way to get two element's (City & State) values so I can use them later. I am looping through every Site under Sites. Every time I go through it, I need to pull the City and State then save them as a string. I have it working (kind of) but I think I'm going about this the wrong way.

XML:

```
<Sites>
  <Site>
    <City>Miami</City>
    <State>FL</State>
    <Machines>
      <Machine>
        <MachineName>1950-16-CORE</MachineName>
        <ServerRoleType>CoreServer</ServerRoleType>
        <ClientRoles>Core</ClientRoles>
        <Features>
          <Feature>
            <FeatureName>CoreProcess</FeatureName>
            <FeatureEnabled>true</FeatureEnabled>
          </Feature>
          <Feature>
            <FeatureName>Antivirus</FeatureName>
            <FeatureEnabled>true</FeatureEnabled>
          </Feature>
      </Machine>
      <Machine>
        <MachineName>1950-16-COREX</MachineName>
        <ServerRoleType>CoreExpansionServer</ServerRoleType>
        <ClientRoles>CoreEx</ClientRoles>
        <Features>
          <Feature>
```

Code:

```
foreach (XElement xEleSite in siteRows)
{
    IEnumerable<XElement> siteLists = from siteList in xEleSite.Descendants("Site")
                                      select siteList;

    IEnumerable<XElement> siteCity = siteLists.Descendants("City");

    foreach (XElement c in siteCity)
    {
        string cityElement = c.Value.ToString();
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this simplified example:

```
<Sites>
  <Site>
    <City>Miami</City>
    <State>FL</State>
    <Machines></Machines>
  </Site>
  <Site>
    <City>NY</City>
    <State>FL</State>
    <Machines></Machines>
  </Site>
</Sites>
```

Suppose `xEleSite` contains this xml, now you can use [Anonymous Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx) to keep info:

```
var result = xEleSite.Descendants("Site")
                     .Select(s => new
                     {
                         City = s.Element("City").Value,
                         State = s.Element("State").Value
                     });
```

To iterate over it you can:

```
foreach (var i in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i.City);
    Console.WriteLine(i.State);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

From the original question, I thought you needed to store all the values from the xml to use it later, while the OP's code had only local variables in the inner-most loop containing them. This approach gives an opportunity to access all the values in a list.